# How do you add the same method to itself after calling it?

Tags: javascript, methods, bluej

I'm pretty new to coding and I don't really understand how to add methods together even though I'm sure it is something really easy to do, or I'm just forgetting to put  something but this is one of the many things that has me stumped.

All I need is to be able to add rollDie to itself in playTurn or something of the same effect.

[Code so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UcHR.png)

[What I have to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWDCb.png)

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you were to include the code in text, rather than in a linked image.  [Here's some information](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) on how to do this. 

You'll also need to include any error messages you're seeing when trying to execute your code.  Copying the exact error message(s) will help. 

Finally, give a list of what you've already tried.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you are looking for:

```
public void playTurn()
{
  // Runs "rollDie()" twice and sums the result, places it in to the variable result
  let result = rollDie() + rollDie();
  
}
```